# Creating iTunes store style home view in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, uicollectionview, itunes-store

I want to build a HomePage like iTunes Homepage.

I mean a general `UICollectionView` with different sections including different`cells`. The `UICollectionView` scrolls vertically but each section scrolls horizontally.

See below image.

[image]

I thought of putting a `UICollectionView` in the `UITableCell`, but get various different runtime errors.

> UITableView collectionView:numberOfItemsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fb009064800

My question is can you help me solve the problem or do you have better way to build this style?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: __10.2 Apps that look similar to Apps bundled on iOS or Watch OS devices, including the App Store, iTunes Store, and iBooks Store, will be rejected__ ([source](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/)), so I would not do that, however that information might be not solution for your original problem, but maybe considerable.

Comment: @holex Ignoring the rejection,  do you have any idea how to proceed the structure?